# When should "punishment" be used, and when can it be avoided?

Tags: training

[According to this answer here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/2961/846), and it makes a lot of sense, sometimes, you just can't use positive reinforcements.

As the comments also state, some activities such as pulling on a leash, which one might think can not be taught with positive reinforcement, can be.

What guidelines can be used to know the limits of positive reinforcement and punishment in pets?

Comment: Thanks for this interesting question. While waiting for answers I recommend reading this: https://dogmantics.com/progressive-reinforcement-training-manifesto/

Comment: Relevant: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2174/is-corporal-punishment-an-effective-training-method-for-dogs

Comment: Also relevant: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/67/how-should-i-discipline-my-cat-for-bad-behavior/1072 and http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/396/what-is-an-effective-way-to-discipline-a-dog/598

Comment: I think a key difference with many of those other questions is that they sort of assume an approach where you always do X or always do Y, instead of looking at each situation differently. The Answer that I linked to basically says you want X, but tempered by X without Y.  It seems in that case, punishment for Y is most effective, and rewarding X.  But maybe I'm not understanding.

Comment: Worth noting that there's a 3rd option: deterrent.

Comment: Surely this will be different depending on the species?

Comment: @starsplusplus - The inference is about dogs, but clarity would be a good idea here.

Comment: @Johncavan actually one link is about cats,  the other about dogs.

Comment: @avi - Leash pulling isn't normally associated with cats, hence my comment. At any rate, then I have to agree that it's too broad I'm afraid. Training methods are very different for different species and best practices and approaches differ in many situations. This seems very unanswerable as it's phrased.